# How can I replace array matches within a string with tags to highlight, but never overlap tags?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

If my string is:

```
Once upon a midnight dreary,
while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
```

And I wanted to highlight the following strings (sorted by string length to prefer longer string matches) :

```
ponder,weary,weak,ary,red,we
```

I want to end up with:

```
Once upon a midnight dre<span>ary</span>,
while I <span>ponder</span>ed, <span>weak</span> and <span>weary</span>,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
```

How can I avoid (as a simple `str_replace()` might lead me)?

```
Once upon a midnight dre<span>ary</span>,
while I <span>ponde<span>r</span>ed</span>, <span><span>we</span>ak</span> and <span><span>we</span><span>ary</span></span>,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

```
$s = <<< EOF
Once upon a midnight dreary,
while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
EOF;
echo preg_replace('/(^|\s)(weary|weak|we|ary)\b/i', '$1<span>$2</span>', $s);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Once upon a midnight dreary,
while I pondered, <span>weak</span> and <span>weary</span>,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gets me close. But what if I ignore word boundaries?  See `ary` and dre`ary` in my original example. Or `ponder`ed.  The reason is that my array only includes singular and present tense words and I'd like to catch all (most) plurals and past tense as well.

Comment: If you cannot use word boundary then can we use space/end anchor to make complete word?

Comment: I suppose matches may be preceded by a space or a line break or the beginning of a string.  Matches may be followed by any other character, new line, or end of file.

Comment: Thanks! Very close. The only unexpected result was removing spaces between words. So `while I pondered` becomes `while I<span>pondered</span,`. Or `and weary` becomes `and<span>weary</span>`.

Comment: yes I realize that, fixed it now. Please try again.

Comment: It should work for beginning since I have `(^|s)`. I just added `once` in the list of words and it became: `<span>Once</span>`

Comment: Thanks so much. Works solid now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to break the string up by spaces so you have all the words. You could then do your search and replace on each word and but the words back together as a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, but matches may also occur within words.  Just not two overlapping matches.  See `ponder` matching `pondered` in my question above.